# XML Deserialization Coming up NULL

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

My Deserializer executes without exception, but the resulting object is coming up with nulls. The source XML clearly shows values that for some reason are not being set in the target object.  I can't for the life of me figure out why?

Source XML:

```
<soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Could not insert new row - duplicate value in a UNIQUE INDEX column (Unique Index:).</faultstring>
<detail>
    <axlError>
        <axlcode>-239</axlcode>
        <axlmessage>Could not insert new row - duplicate value in a UNIQUE INDEX column (Unique Index:).</axlmessage>
        <request>addRoutePartition</request>
    </axlError>
</detail>
```

Class:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace AXLClassLibrary
{
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Fault", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Fault
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "faultcode")]
    public string Faultcode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "faultstring")]
    public string Faultstring { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "detail")]
    public Detail Detail { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "soapenv", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Soapenv { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "axlError")]
public class AxlError
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "axlcode")]
    public string Axlcode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "axlmessage")]
    public string Axlmessage { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "request")]
    public string Request { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "detail")]
public class Detail
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "axlError")]
    public AxlError AxlError { get; set; }
}
}
```

Deserializer Code:

```
                var resp = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                XDocument xd = XDocument.Parse(resp);
                XNamespace ns1 = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
                XNode faultXML = xd.Descendants(ns1 + "Fault").DescendantNodesAndSelf().First();
                XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
                xRoot.ElementName = "Fault";
                xRoot.Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
                xRoot.IsNullable = false;
                resp = faultXML.ToString();


                Fault currentFault;
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Fault), xRoot);
                using (TextReader readFault = new StringReader(resp))
                {
                    currentFault = (Fault)serializer.Deserialize(readFault);
                }
```

[image: Resulting Object Inspection]

Comment: I think you probably want to check out System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap to get what you are looking for. This looks like a reasonably standard SOAP operation from what I can tell. Namespacing is needed for multiple layers of abstraction, but gets pretty thick to grok which is why everybody loves JSON these days. To quote something I saw in a an error message somewhere "SOAP tastes bad, dude."

Comment: Thanks @VanAmburg, I will look into it.  And believe me, I would much rather use JSON, just not an option with this API. :)